# Account Signup not working?

Tags: php

I have a simple account creation script that is not working. I know that there are no connection errors because the login works fine. Also, I turned on error-reporting (made it -1) but it shows no errors
This is my code in snippets, thanks
HTML

```
<form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="newUsername" placeholder="Username"/>
        <input type="password" name="newPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
        <input type="submit" name="signUp" value="Sign Up!"/>
</form>
```

Then PHP:

```
if($_POST['signUp']) {
    $username = $_POST['newUsername'];
    $pass = $_POST['newPassword'];
    $signedUp = SignUp($Username,$pass);
    echo $signUpCode[$signedUp]; // See the SignUp function in prefunc.php

} elseif($_POST['LogIn']) {
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $loggedIn = LogIn($username,$password);
    echo $logInCode[$loggedIn];

}

$signUpCode = Array(
    "-3"=>"Logged in already - can't sign up!",
    "-2"=>"Username already exists!",
    "-1"=>"Failed to sign up - please try again!",
    "1"=>"Signed up, and logged in successfully!"
);

function SignUp($Username,$Password) { 
    $Username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/","",$Username);
    $u = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE LOWER(Username)=LOWER('$Username')");

    if(getCurrentId()){
        return -3;
    }

    if(!mysql_num_rows($u)) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users SET Username='$Username',Password=''$Password") or die(mysql_error());
        $u = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE LOWER(Username)=LOWER('$Username')");

    if(mysql_num_rows($u)) {
        LogIn($Username,$Password);
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

return -2;
```

}

Comment: typo here - mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users SET Username='$Username',Password=''$Password") it should be mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users SET Username='$Username',Password='$Password'"

Comment: Quotes out of whack `SET Username='$Username',Password=''$Password")` --- `SET Username='$Username',Password='$Password'")` typo am sure (*right?*). Plus, don't use plain text for passwords unless it's just a personal project. Not to mention `mysql_*`

Comment: It works now, thanks, problem is it inserts a blank username

Comment: It's because of this `$username = $_POST['Username'];` while elsewhere you're using `$username = $_POST['newUsername'];`

Comment: Change it to `$username = $_POST['newUsername'];` since you're using `name="newUsername"`

Comment: I have an else statement there to determine the value of it

Comment: I don't see anything related to `$_POST['LogIn']`

Comment: Ignore that please, I didn't put my HTML for login

Comment: It is inserting a blank username due to your variables are not the same case -> `$username = $_POST['newUsername'];` && `$signedUp = SignUp($Username,$pass);`. Change `$username` OR `$Username` to be the same case as the other.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you re executing the insert query?
also the query sintax is wrong, try this: insert into user ( username,password) values ('admin','1234').

finally you must fix security issue, your code is affected by sql injection

Comment: I know, I'm working on making it work before I secure it